# How to persist application model

Tags: c#, xml, database, serialization, model

My c# application needs to persist its model classes to disk.
Initially I tried to do xml serialization. However when I do breaking changes in my model (split one class to two) the saved xml will not deserialize (which is understood).

I thought about applying xslt to upgrade the xml but the xml generated is really complex.

Is it a good idea for me to do custom xml serialization to have a simpler format?
Is it better to use a DB? Upgrading a DB is just running a script.

Comment: For large breaking model changes, I prefer one-time "upgrade" routes. While some changes can be accounted for with basic model versioning (such as adding a new field), others (such as splitting 1->2) cannot. Ideally this stuff happens "while in dev" and can be trivially addressed. You will have similar issues with using a DB -- although I would encourage using your (RDBMS) DB for what it is good for (queryable relationships and relational integrity), and only falling back to object serialization where it makes sense (SQL Server has pretty good XML support, so the line is more blurred there).

Answer (score 0):

Implement [ISerializable](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/yougerthen/102162008172741PM/1.aspx) (binary) / [IXmlSerializable](http://paltman.com/2006/jul/03/ixmlserializable-a-persistable-example/) (xml) and everything should work as expected (but you will have to do a bit more work).